# toggle Margin of class on click on another ID

Tags: css, class, onclick, toggle, margin

i have a massenger in the bottom right like facebook chat with this id

```
<a href="#" title="Instant Messenger" id="js_instant_messenger_link">
```

and i want to change the CSS property of Class .holder

```
.holder {
margin: auto;
width: 980px;
}
```

want to toggle this to

```
.holder {
margin: 0 30px;
width: 980px;
}
```

on click on

```
<a href="#" title="Instant Messenger" id="js_instant_messenger_link">
```

plz help me.

plz guide if there is any jquery or javascript code.

Comment: Just a heads up, you have 2 good answers below, if one of them works for you, you should accept the answer. If not, let us know and we can continue to troubleshoot the issue for you. I'm assuming you're new to SO/SE so in order to get help on future questions, it's best to increase your reputation. People are more likely to help out when they see you have a history of accepting answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick assuming you are using Jquery. Hard to tell without any code though...

```
$("#js_instant_messenger_link").click(function(){
    $(".holder").css("margin", "0 30px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above poster... that should be the answer.

However, if you are not using JQuery or similar, you can simply use:

```
var element = document.getElementById('js_instant_messenger_link');
element.addEventListener("click", function(){element.setAttribute("style","margin:0 30px")},false);
```